# rails - update activerecord column error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to update an ActiveRecord with

```
@post.update_column('post_likes_count', @post.post_likes_count - 1)
```

I'm certain that the @post exists but I'm getting the error message:

```
ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError (post_likes_count is marked as readonly):
```

The model for post is defined as

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :post_comments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :post_likes, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :post_hashtags, :dependent => :destroy
  validates_presence_of :user_id
end
```

What am i doing wrong?

All I'm trying to do is decrement the `post_likes_count` column.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in order to update the counter_cache was to call destroy instead of delete on the children.

My post_likes_count was counting the number of likes a post had. When deleting a post_like, i was calling `@post_like.delete` and then manually trying to decrement the counter.

Because my PostLike model has `counter_cache: true`, if you do `@post_like.destroy` , it decrements the counter in the post table by itself.